# Transaction count mismatch - MARS Batch is still active

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, sqlcommand

I have `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in our c# app's connection string. I have already figured out that I can set that to `false` to prevent this error. I am trying to figure out how to modify my stored procedure to work with `MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

The stored procedure in question is a fairly simple stored procedure that executes 99% of the time from the C# app without issues. However, a few times, I have logged the following error when it executes.

*Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. A transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.*

Stored procedure code:

```
begin try 
begin transaction 
    -- create @NewIDs to hold inserted IDs -- hopefully stop any issues related to @@IDENTITY 
    declare @NewIDs table (MyNewID int)

    insert into users       
    output inserted.id into @NewIDs
    values 
    (
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@Username)), 
        'nothing', 
        'nothing', 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@Email)), 
        @Phone, 
        @ProfileID, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName)), 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)), 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchName)),          
        @Password,           
        GETDATE()
    )

    declare @UserID int
    select top 1 @UserID = MyNewID from @NewIDs

    select @retValue = @UserID 

commit transaction  
return @retValue
end try 
begin catch 
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        rollback transaction

    set @retValue = 0
    return @retValue    
end catch
```